# Javascript - set api json return to a variable not console.log

Tags: javascript, fetch

total JS newbie here. Our office utilizes HCL Leap for form building and I need to write some javascript code to populate a form. Unfortunately, all the examples I seem to be coming across online output results to console.log. I need it to actually get assigned to a variable. Here's an example of some code I've been trying to work with that should populate a form text area with with json output:

```
var UserInfo = (async function getUserInfo() {
  var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  console.log(response.json())
})();

item.setValue(UserInfo);
```

When I preview the code, the form populates instead with "[object Promise]". I assume it's some sort of timing issue with how the code is written. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: `.json` returns a new promise. so give `console.log(await response.json())` a try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White, unfortunately it did not.  Changing "console.log(response.json())" to "console.log(await response.json())" still returns "[object Promise]" inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a *Promise* instead of the response. The response can be parsed later as plain text or as json (like you have done). The catch is the `response.json()` also returns a *Promise*. So you will need an await before `response.json()`. The complete code should be:

```
var UserInfo = await (async function getUserInfo() {
  try{
    var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    var jsonResponse = await response.json()
    return jsonResponse
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }
})();
item.setValue(UserInfo);
```

or in one line

```
var UserInfo = await (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).json()
if(UserInfo)
  item.setValue(UserInfo)
```

Whenever using async/await, you should always wrap it inside try/catch block as it may return Error instead of result

Comment: I attempted the first block of code (for some reason the second block gives an error that it's "missing ) after argument list").  The first block returns the same result; "[object Promise]" in the form area.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's some quirk with Leap.

Comment: I forgot that `.json()` also returns a Promise. You will need another await before assigning to UserInfo.
I have edited the answer

Comment: Also, I have checked the second one it seems fine. Maybe if you can share some more information about the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` all the things:

```js
var UserInfo = (async function getUserInfo() {
  var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  // ``.json` also returns a promise, so use `await` to reference the actual result
  const data = await response.json()
  console.table(data)

  // Since this variable comes from a function expression, explicitly return 
  // `response.json()` to set the final value as intended
  return data
})();

item.setValue(await UserInfo);
```

If the main execution context (with `item.setValue`) isn't inside an `async` function,
you will have to wrap it with an async IIFE in order to use `await` to set `item.value()`.

> The await keyword is only valid inside async functions. If you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a SyntaxError.
> [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description)

```js
(async () => {
  
  var UserInfo = await (async function getUserInfo() {
    var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    // ``.json` also returns a promise, so use `await` to reference the actual result
    const data = await response.json()
    console.table(data)

    // Since this variable comes from a function expression, explicitly return 
    // `response.json()` to set the final value as intended
    return data
  })();

  item.setValue(UserInfo);
})();
```

Here's another way, if you need to avoid using an `async` wrapper in the upper scope:

```js
// Simplify this method, not an IIFE any more
async function getUserInfo() {
  var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  const data = await response.json()
  
  console.table(data)
  return data
};

// This part doesn't need to exist inside an async function
getUserInfo()
  .then((info) => item.setValue(info))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

Comment: HCL Leap isn't liking this code for some reason.  I get the error "Javascript is invalid - Reason: missing ) after argument list"  I'm not spotting any missing bracket, though.

Comment: Dang, sorry. It works when pasted into Chrome's console. I'm not familiar with HCL... I do know that in javascript you can't use `await` outside of an `async function()` though. You might want to try wrapping your main execution context in an async IIFE like in this example to see if that's causing the bracket warning: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage

Answer (score 0):

```
const UserInfo =  async () => {
  const response = await 
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  return response.json();
};

UserInfo().then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  //set data to field
  //item.setValue(data)
}).catch(error => {
  throw error
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be helpful

```
var UserInfo = (async function getUserInfo() {
  var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  var data = await response.json()
  // One way
  console.log(data)

  // Or, even better
  // You can use the console to put a message, and then, send also an object
  // You can also capture more information
  console.log('Console entry - Result of API:', { ApiResult: data, data, anotherValue: 'Hello world' })
})();

item.setValue(UserInfo);
```

Another approach it's using the promises:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ACM.jpg
[image]

Comment: You forgot return. UserInfo will always be undefined

Comment: Hmm.  Same result.  The form just returns "[object Promise]".

Comment: Really? seems that's working: https://imgur.com/8k9Jise